# expand the product $\prod_{i=1}^n(a_i+b_i)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a formula to expand the product $\prod_{i=1}^n(a_i+b_i)$, where $a_i,b_i$ are elements of a commutative domain?

Comment: Nothing simple. Every term of the expansion is a single term of the for $a_{i_1}a_{i_2}...a_{i_k}b_{i_{k+1}}b_{i_{k+2}}...b_n$ where the $i_j$ are distinct values from one to $n$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There really isn't a good formula.

If you define, for $S\subseteq \{1,2,...,n\}$: $$a(S)=\prod_{i\in S} a_i\\b(S)=\prod_{i\in S} b_i$$

then $$\prod_{i=1}^{n} (a_i+b_i)=\sum_{S\subseteq\{1,...,n\}} a(S)b(S^{c})$$

Where $S^c=\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}\setminus S$ is the complement of $S$.

This essentially means that each term in the expansion must contain exactly one of $a_i,b_i$ for each $i$.

[Note, an empty product - when $S=\emptyset$ - is defined to be $1$.]